# mvn -Dxy.skip=true has no effect

Tags: maven

Many maven plugins have a configuration option "skip" that should skip the execution of the plugin. It seems as if setting those options on the command line has no effect:

```
[james@JAMES-PC ~/er]$ mvn clean test -Dpmd.skip=true -Dlicense.skip=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

... etc.etc.

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-license-plugin:1.4.0:check (check-headers) @ eranger ---
[INFO] Checking licenses...
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1:check (pmd-check) @ eranger >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1:pmd (pmd) @ eranger ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1:check (pmd-check) @ eranger <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1:check (pmd-check) @ eranger ---

... etc.etc.
```

The pmd and the license plugins still get executed. Any ideas how to really skip them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is loaded but not fully executed; otherwise, you'd see a lot of output of PMD analyzing your code.

The reason why this happens is that the option `pmd.skip` is evaluated by the PMD plugin itself, so Maven has to load it. The plugin will check the option and exit immediately.

If that is still too much for you, move the plugin into a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

**[EDIT]** Since the maven-license-plugin should support `skip` ([see the docs](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/wiki/Configuration#maven-license-plugin_configuration_options)), you have probably found a bug.

I suggest to:

1. File a bug report
2. Move the plugin into a profile (see above)

Comment: But the license plugin e.g. still checks all files. I can see debug logs like "[DEBUG] Header OK in: C:\some\file.java"  when running mvn -Dlicense.skip=true -X.

Comment: which plugin is that? Please post the URL of the home page.

Comment: That's the [maven-license-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: We used an older version of the maven-license-plugin, where the skip parameter has not been supported yet. This explains a lot...